# Is there a Sublime Text package that serves similar function like the MDN References Intellisense popups of vscose?

Tags: popup, mozilla

I am switching to ST from Vscode and I'm used to the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) popups that tell me what elements and attributes do, I want something like that in ST. I have searched and didn't find any

I installed a MDN Search Doc package but it doesn't work like the MDN popups in VScode